# What does "日数" mean here?

Tags: translation

From manga where student is being scolded.

> 来週会議があるの
>
> 出席日数が足りてるか
>
> 赤点取った数が多くないか

It's a long sentence so I'm having trouble.

I think I can understand that the teacher has a meeting next week. It's the following words I'm confused with. Is the teacher saying the student's about to fail?

Comment: Isn't there a break between あるの and 出席?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "It's a long sentence so I'm having trouble."

Long sentences are not too often used in manga.  Sentences just tend to "look" long to Japanese-learners because there are practically no punctuations used in manga.

「日数{にっすう}」 simply means what the two kanji would suggest -- "***the number of days***".

Thus, 「[出席]{しゅっせき}日数」 means "***the (total) number of days attended*** (at school)".

> "We have a meeting next week."
>
> "(We will discuss whether) you have attended school for a sufficient number of days."
>
> "and whether you have not received too many F's."

「赤点{あかてん}」 is a school slang for "Fail".

Comment: "(We will discuss) whether..."